# Why do I get the search bar in a separate line?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-search

I am trying to add a Google search bar in the `navbar`, but i do not why it comes in a new line as shown below:

[image]

This is the html that should brings the `navbar` and its components all in the same column.

```
<div class='col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12'>            
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
              <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                </button>
              </div>

              <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                  <li><a href="./our-activities.html">Activities</a></li>
                  <li><a href="./our-vision.html">Vision</a></li>
                  <li><a href="./ngo-structure.html">Structure</a></li>
                  <li><a href="./by-laws.html">By-Laws</a></li>
                </ul>
               <!-- search bar -->
                <div>
                    <script>
                    (function() {
                      var cx = '001581938009576517320:-1og4oqxb-y';
                      var gcse = document.createElement('script');
                      gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
                      gcse.async = true;
                      gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
                          '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
                      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                      s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
                    })();
                  </script>
                  <gcse:search></gcse:search>
                </div>

              </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
          </nav>
      </div>
```

What could be the reason I am getting search-bar in a different/new line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to float search bar container in order to align it with navbar menu items. For this purpose you can simply add `pull-left` (or `pull-right`) class to the search bar `div`. You will also need to set some fixed width like `col-sm-6` for 50% width, otherwise it's 100% by default.

```
<div class="pull-left col-sm-6">
    <script>
        (function() {
            var cx = '001581938009576517320:-1og4oqxb-y';
            var gcse = document.createElement('script');
            gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
            gcse.async = true;
            gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
                '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
        })();
    </script>
    <gcse:search></gcse:search>
</div>
```

After that you can further customize search bar styles by overwriting default ones, e.g.:

```
.navbar .cse .gsc-control-cse, 
.navbar .gsc-control-cse {
    padding: 9px 0 0;
    background: inherit;
    border: 0;
}
```

#### Demo: http://run.plnkr.co/FMCuEPGojpv3n8OM/

Answer (score 0):

```
.googlesearch {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    width: 500px;
}
```

`position: absolute;` is the key to arrange these kind of objects that created programmatically.